# Is it possible to comment heroku build

Tags: heroku

Is there any possibility how to comment a deployed build on heroku?

For example, I want to put a simple comment before releasing a new version to the production, like version x.y.z. - stable

So if the build from a stage pipeline somehow failed, i know where to return...

I hope there is such an addon, but I guess this should be somehow part of heroku, shouldn't it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can leave an [annotated tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#Annotated-Tags) in your Git repo.

Comment: Thank you @mipadi, but what if I change only the environmental settings, that are not stored in git...

Comment: @Andrej: I don't think that's possible.